# Dynamic table rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to add/remove rows/columns in my table but I don't how to achieve this given my knowledge in js/jquery is basic. I've search and seen related topics but none fits to what I wanted to happen.

As you can see in my code below I have 11 columns with the `<th>` tag and a default row and they must not be affected by remove. Also, when adding new column the PO increments like PO 10.

```
<table class="main-table" id="po-table" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table-header">
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Course Code</td>
            <td>Course Name</td>
            <td>PO 1</td>
            <td>PO 2</td>
            <td>PO 3</td>
            <td>PO 4</td>
            <td>PO 5</td>
            <td>PO 6</td>
            <td>PO 7</td>
            <td>PO 8</td>
            <td>PO 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="default-row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="course_code[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="course_name[]"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po1[]" value="Po1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po2[]" value="Po2"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po3[]" value="Po3"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po4[]" value="Po4"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po5[]" value="Po5"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po6[]" value="Po6"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po7[]" value="Po7"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po8[]" value="Po8"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="po9[]" value="Po9"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Picture of the output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your body
http://www.redips.net/javascript/adding-table-rows-and-columns/

```js
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<button onclick="addCol()">Add Column</button>


<button onclick="removeRow()">Remove Row</button>
<button onclick="removeCol()">Remove Column</button>

<script>
var table = document.getElementById("po-table");

function addRow() {
    
    var lastrow = table.rows.length;
 var lastcol = table.rows[0].cells.length; 
 var row = table.insertRow(lastrow); 
 var cellcol0 = row.insertCell(0);
 cellcol0.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='course_code[]'></input>";
 var cellcol1 = row.insertCell(1);
 cellcol1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='course_name[]'></input>";
 
 for(i=2; i<lastcol;i++)
 {
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(i);
  cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='pos[]'></input>";
 }
    
}
function addCol() {
    
    var lastrow = table.rows.length;
 var lastcol = table.rows[0].cells.length;
 var headertxt = table.rows[0].cells[lastcol-1].innerHTML;
 var headernum = headertxt.slice(headertxt.indexOf("PO")+2);
 headernum = headernum.trim();
 
    //for each row add column
 for(i=0; i<lastrow;i++)
 {
  
  var cell1 = table.rows[i].insertCell(lastcol);
  if(i==0)
   cell1.innerHTML = "PO " + (Number(headernum)+1);
  else
   cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='pos[]'></input>";
  
 }
}

function removeRow(){
 var lastrow = table.rows.length;
 if(lastrow<2){
  alert("You have reached the minimal required rows.");
  return;
 }
 table.deleteRow(lastrow-1);
}

function removeCol(){

 var lastcol = (table.rows[0].cells.length)-1;
 var lastrow = (table.rows.length);
 //disallow first two column removal unless code is add to re-add text box columns vs checkbox columns
 if(lastcol<3){
  alert("You have reached the minimal required columns.");
  return;
 }
 
  //for each row remove column
 for(i=0; i<lastrow;i++)
 {
  table.rows[i].deleteCell(lastcol);
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you've understood and perceived what I wanted more ways better than I do. Thank you very much good sir :D

Comment: I hope this is not too late but could you help again sir? I added a new column before Course Code and is about the row's number. Like everytime the user adds new row, it'll be 2, 3 and so on. I've done some editing both my code and yours. I edited my post above.

Comment: @Meltdowner If you have a new question, then create a new question for that, instead of modifying the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just clone the current row and append it to the table with the following jQuery:

```
$(".default-row").clone().insertAfter(".default-row:last-child");
```

An example of it working is here: http://jsfiddle.net/05Lo1sm6/

Answer (score 0):

***For Dynamic creation of tables with respect to entered row and column, you can use this code***

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset=utf-8 /> 
<title>Dynamic Table</title> 
<script>
function createTable()
{
rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);
cn = window.prompt("Input number of columns",1);

 for(var r=0;r<parseInt(rn,10);r++)
  {
   var x=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(r);
   for(var c=0;c<parseInt(cn,10);c++)  
    {
     var y=  x.insertCell(c);
     y.innerHTML="Row-"+r+" Column-"+c; 
    }
   }
}

</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
body {margin: 30px;} 
</style>  
</head><body> 
<table id="myTable" border="1"> 
</table><form> 
<input type="button" onclick="createTable()" value="Create the table"> 
</form></body></html>
```